Is the first paper attempting to apply Hilbert space theory to quantum mechanics in 1926 Germany available for free online?
I would like to view the quantum mechanics paper "Über die Jacobischen Transformationen der Quantenmechanik," published in Germany in 1926 by Fritz Wolfgang London. The reference is Z. Phys. 1926, 37, 915–925. I searched for it online but couldn't find a free version. I also checked the Internet Archive but couldn't locate it there. If it is available somewhere, please let me know.
Incidentally, this paper is likely the first attempt to apply Hilbert space theory to the understanding of quantum mechanics. I am currently exploring how quantum mechanics was systematically developed mathematically by reviewing the papers from that era in order. I would appreciate your assistance.


London published two papers on the subject in 1926, both are discussed by Lacki, which, I think, is freely accessible. But the copyright on the original papers is owned by Springer and they would not be freely accessible except through libraries or shadow sites like Sci-Hub.

Another job for a local research librarian…

1926 is now at the copyright cut-off year for google-books availability (at least where I'm at), something that I especially keep track of since I don't have access to stuff behind paywalls. And when I checked at google-books (phrase search for title, restricted  to 1920-1930; found volume 40 of the journal on the first page of hits; clicked on  "More editions"; looked through the hits until I got to volume 37), I found it, which took all of about 45 seconds -- London's 1926 paper.

Thanks for helping me find the paper, Dave! Do you have the full text on your PC? I can't access it from my computer. I think it's because the phone number linked to resetting my Google account isn't associated with this one. My smartphone's a bit hard to use right now, so I'll try setting it up later.

Hi, Jon. I'm residing in Japan, where there's a scarcity of proficient English-speaking librarians. Consequently, I can't depend on them extensively for research on English or German literature.

I just downloaded the volume, but unfortunately it's 43.6 MB and I'm limited to emailing 25 MB (yahoo email) and I don't know how to extract the 11 page article from the 1020 page .pdf file. However, I can make screen shots of each of those 11 pages (actually, to better read them, I'll use a larger view, so it will be 3 screenshots per journal page) and email those to you. Let me know if you want me to do this. If so, send me an email (for me to have your email). My email address is at my profile.

https://archive.org/details/zeitschrift-fur-physik-vol-37/page/915/mode/1up?view=theater

THX, Dave. Do you mean that it is possible to download the mentioned journal from Google Books? I tried again earlier but couldn't do it. Is it because it can't be done from Japan, but can be done from your country, or is it something that requires a change in settings?

THX M. Lonardi for finding the paper through your search. I also tried searching on Internet Archive yesterday but didn’t have any luck. Could you please tell me how you conducted your search? Additionally, could you help me find another paper by the same author, published in 1926, titled "Winkelvariable und Kanonische Transformationen in der Undulationsmechanik"? The bibliographic information is Zs. f. Phys., 40, 193-210 (1926). This is actually the paper I’ve been looking for. I just realized that in my previous query, I specified a different paper by the same author from the same year!

Is it because it can't be done from Japan, but can be done from your country, or is it something that requires a change in settings? --- I suppose it could be either of these two possibilities. For me when selecting the link I provided, if you select the menu for the 6-spoked wheel in the upper-right of the Google Books toolbar, I get these options: "Try the new Google Books // My library // Help // Advanced Book Search // Download EPUB // Download PDF // Plain text" You may need a google account, I don't know -- I've had one since late 2004, but not a Gmail account (that I'm aware of).

Dave, I posted a question about this on the Google forum, and the response was that Google Books will tell you which page the content you're looking for is on, but you can't view the full text, even if it's a scholarly journal from a hundred years ago. Just now, I clicked the 'Try the new Google Books' button as you instructed, but I'm not sure what to do next. By the way, I'm currently using the Japanese veDave,

Given that Japanese researchers have been reading and citing non-Japanese language articles for 100 years or more, I bet that a research librarian in Japan can find the material just fine. Have you actually tried?

Jon, thanks to the exponential development of interactive AI like ChatGPT, as well as free translation sites like DeepL, it's now easier to casually read even 'Principia' in your mother tongue once you find it on the web. However, in Japan, there are few historians of science or mathematics who have a solid grasp of multiple languages, and even fewer among library librarians. While I once asked my local library in Japan to find a historical paper in German online, it doesn't always work out so smoothly,

Have you tried logging in to your Google account first?

I clicked the 'Try the new Google Books' button as you instructed --- I did not say to select this button, and in fact I hate the "new Google Books" format because it puts an annoying screen with the snippet text in the way when I'm simply searching for something. When it randomly (every few weeks, it seems) changes things for me so that I'm dealing with the "new Google Books" format, I immediately fiddle around and try to get things back to what I'm used to and which works better for the type of searches I do.

I did, of course, mdewey.
